# OpenJDK@11 exec format error on Windows Subsystem Linux Ubuntu

Tags: java, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using WSL Ubuntu with zsh. I pulled in OpenJDK@11 using homebrew. When I try to run java I get the following error:

```
~$ java --version
zsh: exec format error: java
~$ which java
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin/java
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Indeed, very peculiar. I have a similar issue. I built a Docker image in WSL2, based on the openjdk image and I am getting "exec format error" when trying to run this image on another system. Build and target system are both amd64 and for Java it shouldn't matter anyway. I am also using Java 11, in this case.